# Multiple Tableviews in UIScrollview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm adding multiple tableviews into the scrollview based on the array count...and the code is here

```
int currentX = 3;
for(int i=0;i<[restNameArray count]; i++)
{

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(currentX, 0, 150, 35)];
    button.tag = i+1;
    //[button setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ohris_applytics_ipad_middle_oc.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold" size:15.0f];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [restNameArray objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    restaurantTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(currentX, 35, 150, 310) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [restaurantTable setTag:i+1];
    [restaurantTable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    restaurantTable.delegate = self;
    restaurantTable.dataSource = self;
    [scrollView addSubview:button];
    [scrollView addSubview:restaurantTable];

    NSLog(@"tag %d",restaurantTable.tag);
    currentX = restaurantTable.frame.size.width+currentX+3;

    [tagArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", restaurantTable.tag]];
}
NSLog(@"aaaa %@", tagArray);
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(currentX, 349)];
```

It is showing fine in the simulator. And i need to populate the tableviews with array.
And the code at cellforrowatindexpath is

```
   if(tableView == restaurantTable){
    for (int i =0;i<[tagArray count];i++)
    {
      table1Array = [[[restSalesArray objectAtIndex:i]componentsSeparatedByString:@","]mutableCopy];

    NSLog(@"Sales array :%d %@", i, table1Array);
    cell.textLabel.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[table1Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]intValue]]];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }
}
```

But the problems is, it is populating only in the last tableview.. remaining are empty... plz help me out guys....

Comment: create each tableview in the loop and get the tableview against its tag you are setting

Answer (score 3):

It is ok what you are trying to do. But you are overriding the `restaurantTable` variable in your for loop. So the variable is the last table view. You need to add them to an array or seperate variables to be able to compare with if in you `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

_allTableViews is defined in your header file

you for loop

```
_allTableViews = [NSMutableArray array];  

for (.....) {
.
.
.
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWith....];

.
.
.

[_allTableViews addObject tableView];
}
```

cellForRowAtIndePath

```
NSInteger tableIndex = [_allTableViews indexOfObject:tableView];
// Now you have the index of table view
switch (tableIndex) {
case 0:
// first table
break;
case 1:
// second table
break;
default:
break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to compare each tableView either by its outlet name or tag.

As :

```
if(tableView == _restaurantTableOutlet){ 
    ...
}
else  if(tableView == _barTableOutlet){
    ...
}
else  if(tableView == _loungeTableOutlet){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing each table view into `restaurantTable`, so the references to previous table views are lost. Either store them all in an array, or don't store any of them

Why are you checking `if(tableView == restaurantTable)`? You should check the tables by tag and work with each one separately

Answer (score 0):

You have to first assign tag for each tableView. Then you can get selected row of particular table by following code:-

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int tableTag = tableView.tag;
    if(tableTag==0)
    {
         //do something here
    }
    else if(tableTag==1)
    {
         //do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: Y ur going to DidSelectRow method.. I need to populate the tableview first ..... Thanks anyways for the reply